# ValueError: The keyword argument `name` must be the name of a method of the decorated class:

Tags: python, django

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from briefcase.BaseBriefcaseView import BaseBriefcaseView

from briefcase.models import Customer

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BriefcaseIndexView(BaseBriefcaseView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'briefcase/index.html'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from briefcase.views import BriefcaseIndexView, invoice_view


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', BriefcaseIndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^index/invoice_view$', invoice_view.as_view(), name='invoice'),

]
```

## BaseBriefcase.py

```
from cmms.views import DefaultContextView


class BaseBriefcaseView(DefaultContextView):
    extra_context = {}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseBriefcaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["side_menu"] = self.get_side_menu()
        context["main_menu"] = self.get_main_menu()
        context["side_filter"] = self.get_side_filter()
        context["module"] = "Briefcase"
        return context
```

And the error i get is.......

> ValueError: The keyword argument name must be the name of a method of . >  the decorated class: . Got 'dispatch' instead

Please help a django newbie. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show `DefaultContextView`.

Comment: I agree with @Sayse that `LoginRequiredMixin` is tidier. However, your use of `method_decorator` looks OK. There's probably something odd in `DefaultContextView`, which you still haven't shown.

Comment: I have edited to include it. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: You've added `BaseBriefcaseView`, but you still haven't shown `DefaultContextView`.

Answer (score 2):

To apply `login_required` to a class based view, you should use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin)

```
class BriefcaseIndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, DefaultContextView):
```

Comment: Don't forget: 
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin